low AIC on Skew-Normal AFT
I am interested in making an AFT model based on the Skew-Normal distribution. For this I am basing myself on the following article. When running the model and comparing it with others such as Weibull, Exponential, Logistic, Gamma, I find that the AIC and BIC is better in the Skew-Normal model, but when graphing the curves and comparing with the Kaplan-Meier estimator, the SN model curve does not fit (visually) very well. What is happening here? I tried searching in the literature or on the internet but didn't find much information. I would appreciate any kind of help or references. I attach my code and images
f_x_sn =  function(x,xi,sigma,alpha){
  return( 1/(sigma * x)  * dsn(log(x), xi,sigma,alpha ) )
}

S_x_sn = function(x,xi,sigma,alpha){
  return( 1-psn( log(x),xi,sigma,alpha ) )
}

skew_normal = function( parametros ){
  
  sigma = parametros[1]
  
  alpha = parametros[2]
  
  betas = parametros[3:length(parametros)] # without covariates
  
  X = matrix(1, nrow(data),1 )
  
  log_like = sum( delta*( log(f_x_sn(time, X%*%betas,sigma, alpha ) )  )) + 
    sum( (1 - delta  ) * log( S_x_sn(time, X%*%betas,sigma, alpha ) )  )  
  
  return(log_like)
}

inicial_1_4 = c(1,1,1)  
resultado_1_4 = optim(par = inicial_1_4, fn = skew_normal, control = list(fnscale = -1))
resultado_1_4$par

for example, in the dataset ``leukemia'' from survival (survival::leukemia) i have
> 2*3 - 2*skew_normal( resultado_1_4$par )
[1] 157.4882
> AIC(ggamma_model4)
[1] 166.6783
> AIC(exp_model4)
[1] 168.6359
> AIC(weibull_model4)
[1] 170.3573
> AIC(loglogistic_fit4)
[1] 165.1117

with models fitted without covariates (using flexsurv). And the plot is


To me the fit isn't so bad visually, but there aren't many events. This isn't the best way to evaluate the choice of distribution family for an AFT model particularly when there are covariates to consider. See this page and its links. You estimate the residuals in scaled log(T) around the predictions. To deal with right-censoring, you compare a Kaplan-Meier plot of the residuals against what would have been predicted from the standard distribution of the chosen family. Try that and see what you get.
